# Разъясните с месторасположением класса с данными для Hibernate

Tags: java, intellij-idea, hibernate, maven

Такое дело. Осваиваю Хибернэйт, всё вроде нормально, но вот не хочет Хибер хавать мой класс User, который лежит, согласно рекомендациям Maven в `main/java/ru/java2017/hibernate` (синяя стрелка). Ему мол подавай пакет:`main/java` (красная стрелка), тогда всё в поряде.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чую, дело в настройках. Пошукал в нете - не вник.
Вот на всякий пожарный, файлы:

hibernate.cfg.xml

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//hibernate/hibernate Configuration DTD//EN" "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate?useSSL=false</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name="useSSL=false">false</property>
        <mapping resource="user.cfg.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>`

user.cfg.xml

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="User" table="user">
        <id name="id" column="id">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="firstname" column="first_name" type="string" />
        <property name="lastname" column="last_name" type="string" />
        <property name="age" column="age" type="int" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>`

Как мне сделать так, чтобы мой класс User находился именно в дирректории `main/java/ru/java2017/hibernate` и чтоб Hibernat его ел?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `user.cfg.xml` укажите *полное* имя класса, т.е. вместе с пакетами:

```
<class name="ru.java2017.hibernate.User" ...>
```

иначе hibernate не узнает, что вы имели в виду именно этот класс.

Comment: Спасибо, всё так просто оказалось!